# Open documents from Team Explorer with Notepad++

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, team-explorer

My team uses the documents feature of Team Explorer 2012 to store release notes and stuff. Whenever I open one of these documents from the Team Explorer documents panel, it launches the URL in Firefox.

In the case of a .sql file, Firefox prompts me to download the file or open it with another application. But in the case of a .txt file, it just displays it in the browser.

When I right click one of these documents and choose edit from the context menu in the Team Explorer documents panel, it opens the file in Windows Notepad.

I can't find any option in Firefox or in Visual Studio to change this behavior, and I'd like to open the document in Notepad++. How can I do this?

Comment: Re: votes to close, I wasn't sure if this question belongs here or Super User.

Answer (score 1):

**To change the default editor for an existing file**

On the File menu in Visual Studio, choose Open and then select File.

In the Open File dialog box, select a file of the type you want to change.

For example, if you want to change the default editor for text files, select a .txt file.

Still in the Open File dialog box, click the down arrow next to the Open button, and then select Open With.

In the Open With dialog box, choose an editor from the Select a program to open list.

Click the Set as Default button and then click the Open button to open the file.

**To add an editor to the Open With dialog box**

On the File menu in Visual Studio, choose Open and then select File.

In the Open File dialog box, select a file of the type you want to change.

Choose the arrow adjacent to the Open button, and then select Open With.

In the Open With dialog box, choose Add.

In the Add Program dialog box, enter the path and name of the executable program (.exe) for the editor you want to add.

In the Friendly Name text box, type a unique name for the editor that you want to include in the Open With dialog box.

In the Add Program dialog box, choose OK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hy2sthf1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I followed the steps for opening a .txt file in Visual Studio, but when I open a .txt file from the documents panel in Team Explorer part of Visual Studio it still displays it in Firefox. Also, when I right click on a file a select edit from the context menu it opens it in Windows Notepad. Any ideas?